# Unable to inject $resource in jasmine unit test

Tags: angularjs, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine, jasmine2.0

Im trying to test a service I have written that makes use of $resource, but am having problems when attempting to inject $resource into my test spec.

I am using Typescript with AngularJS 1.6.x and my service class looks is follows:

```
export class MyDataService {

  constructor(
    private $resource: ng.resource.IResourceService
    ) {
    this.someResource = $resource('api/some-endpoint');
  }

  public getThings() {
    return this.someResource.get().$promise;
  }
}
```

And my test spec (using Jasmine + Karma):

```
import { MyDataService } from './my-data-service.service';

describe('MyDataService Tests:', function() {
  let myDataService: MyDataService;
  let $resource: ng.resource.IResourceService;
  let resourceSpy: jasmine.Spy;

  beforeEach(inject(function(_$resource_){
    $resource = _$resource_;
    myDataService = new MyDataService($resource,);
    resourceSpy = spyOn(myDataService.resource, 'get');
  }));
  afterEach(function() {
    resourceSpy.calls.reset();
  });

  describe('when calling getThings', function() {
    it('should call get on the underlying resource instance', function() {
      myDataService.getThings(1, 15);
      expect(resourceSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });
```

I am getting `Unknown provider: $resourceProvider <- $resource` and I have made sure that angular-resource is being included as part of my Karma config.

I am also making use of angular-mocks with Karma, and I did wonder is this error because $resource is not part of the mocks library? I am not declaring any angular modules to load as part of tests, as I just want to test the classes in isolation, rather than having to load up an entire module.

Thanks

Comment: You should probably add `beforeEach(angular.mock.module('ng-resource'));`.

After some time I think that these isolated test makes no sense - often you have quite a lot dependecies in your service - constants, other services, $q, etc.
This makes manual injecting all dependencies such a pain, also when you add/remove some dependecy - you always need to rewrite your test. So better dont start writing these tests)

Comment: Thanks @PetrAveryanov - that got me past the error. So are you saying I would better off sticking with traditional approach when it comes to testing my own service, so load the module that contains my service, e.g. `beforeEach(module('my-module'));`

Comment: Yes, cause usually your service1 depend on your service2 that depends on your service3. And testing all in isolation is hard and not that effective.

Answer (score 0):

@PetrAveryanov has the correct answer. I would point out that—unless there's some fancy camel case checks going on in OP's Jasmine but not my copy of Jest—since that post, the module's name has changed to `ngResource`: `beforeEach(angular.mock.module('ngResource'));`